# PTIJ: Fire codes in the Beis Hamikdash

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

How did the fire extinguisher/sprinkler system not put out the fire on the altar? There's an Issur of [לא תכבה](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.6.5) for one to extinguish the fire. More importantly, when the 3rd Beis Hamikdash is rebuilt, will there be any fire extinguishers installed? Emergency exits? Any sprinkler systems?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Plenty of emergency exits in the first two. See Mishnayos in Middos. There were more gates than one or two in the Ezras Nashim.

Comment: Dont understand the question. Why would you want to put it out. And since it came from heaven not sure if fire extinguishers would work on it. I suppose it would work otherwise there wouldnt be an issur. But since not all the fire came from heaven that is no proof. The third bais hamikdosh will be made with fire so extinguishers wouldnt work. 'bo'aish ato osid livnosa'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer..

The altars are all outdoors. Where would you hang the fire extinguishers?

As for sprinklers - they had that already. They're called Cohanim. They sprinkle blood. I've never experimented with this, myself, but, I'd imagine that blood is good at extinguishing fires, unless you're angry when you do it. Then, the blood would boil first.

The 3rd Bet Hamikdash would encounter the same arrangement, I would assume.

As for emergency exits - why would any type of emergency occur in the Bet Hamikdash? This is the place where God is present and his protection is constantly there. If one doesn't have full faith in God while in the Bet Hamikdash, then, something is drastically wrong with that person.

Comment: Plenty of water, and if nothing else it'll suffocate the fire if enough is thrown on top.

Comment: The golden altar was not outdoors.